# VB.NET - How to Create Information Box

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms, winforms

I'm creating a form that will display a long list of properties and their associated value. I'd like to display them in a sort of table-like control. Something with heading values at the top and a list of organized data underneath it. Something like these:

[image: example]
[image: another example]

I realize those 2 examples aren't exactly the same but I'm flexible on what I produce as long as it gives a similar effect. My question is, how do I create a list like that? Is there a control in the Visual Studio toolbox that will produce this effect?

I'm sure there's something similar that easy to find but I can't figure out what to call that control so my searches haven't turned up anything useful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) controls.

Comment: ListView can be really flexible! No need for 3rd party controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are windows form controls that provides this functionality.

For the tabbed windows use the [TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx):

[image]

For the different lists use a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) control in the mode `Details` - which means a list with columns:

[image]

For the second feature, the `ListView` control has the `Group` features:

[image]

In order to group items togheter set the group for the chosen item(s):

[image]

All of this can be of course done programatically. There are good tutorials on MSDN and Channel9.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots! This gives me exactly what I need to know. I'm accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of ListView and TabControl controls could be used to emulate what you're showing above. See the links for [ListView](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/listview-control-with-multiple-column-in-vb.net) and [TabControl](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/Tutorials/Controls/TabControl.html) to help you get started.

Comment: I don't care about the TabControl (I wasn't clear about that in the OP) but the ListView is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!